# Server receive unencoded characters using Java socket

Tags: java, sockets, encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to send a message from a computer and read it from another using java socket. The problem is that the message received by the server is something unencoded represented by two question marks inside a diamond.

To read and write I use the following objects:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter( socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"), true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")));
```

And the methods:

```
out.println("OK");
in.readLine();
```

Comment: You must be sending something else as well. Possibly via the underlying socket streams rather than these readers and writers.

Comment: I'm quite sure that's the first message I send

Comment: I just read a message, if it's ok I send an ok otherwise I send an error

Comment: With some debug we found out the issue just concern the first message. The following ones are read and printed correctly

Answer (score 0):

Use DataInputStream and DataOutputStream to read/write the socket. These have readUTF() and writeUTF() methods which will send Strings properly.

Comment: There is no reason why the code shown wouldn't work just as well on strings.